# "On the last week" or "In the last week"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I'm planning a trip. My plane lands on the 29th of August. Should I say:

> I'll arrive *on* the last week of August.

or

> I'll arrive *in* the last week of August.

Web searches show that both prepositions are used; reading a [reference website](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/prepositions.htm) made me more inclined towards "in", though I am still not sure.

Comment: at a time, on a day, in a week, month, or year.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[According to Google Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=+in+the+last+week+of%2Con+the+last+week&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20last%20week%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20last%20week%3B%2Cc0), "in the last week of..." is much more common. This fits with my feeling as a native speaker, too: *in* or *during* for a range of time like a week, month, or season ("in the last week of August"); *on* for a specific day ("on August tenth"); *at* for a specific time ("at 4pm").

Comment: +1 for not being tempted to say "on" is "incorrect", even though "in" is more common by over 50:1. Having said that, I would strongly recommend your succinct guide to anyone who's not sure which preposition to use! :)

Answer (score 7):

From this article on [prepositions](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/prepositions.htm):

**Prepositions of Time: at, on, and in**

> We use **at** to designate specific times. *The train is due at 12:15 p.m.*
>
> We use **on** to designate days and dates.
>
> *My brother is coming on Monday.*
>
> *We're having a party on the Fourth of July.*
>
> We use **in** for nonspecific times during a day, a month, a season, or a year.
>
> *She likes to jog in the morning.*
>
> *It's too cold in winter to run outside.*
>
> *He started the job in 1971.*
>
> *He's going to quit in August.*

Your sentence specifies that a plane will be arriving some time in the last week of August. Since this is a nonspecific time, you would say:

> I'll arrive in the last week of August.

If, however, you do choose to say that you'll arrive exactly on the 29th of August, this is a specific day so you would say:

> I'll arrive on the 29th of August.

You could, however, choose to drop the preposition (as another person answered), but only do so if you feel comfortable--people will understand the sentence both with and without "on", so you don't need to change your speaking/writing style if you want to take someone's advice.

Answer (score 6):

As an American, I would drop the preposition altogether.  The present participle (-ing) also feels appropriate for relating arrivals and departures:

"I'll be arriving the last week of August" is what feels natural to me.

Or simpler: "I arrive the last week of August."

You could use "in" with a specific month ("I'll arrive in August.") or season, but not for a week.

Only use "on" with one specific day ("I'll arrive on August 29th.")

Answer (score 1):

While both would be understood, my preference between the two would be the latter, using *in*.  I'll note that without a choice there, I would have suggested *during* to replace either *on* or *in*.

Interestingly, I'll contrast this with the following set:

> I'll arrive on the fourth of August.
>
> I'll arrive in the fourth of August.

In this case, *on* would be preferable.